# Modifying the trigger collection fields

Tags: apex, trigger

In a trigger's `before insert` context, I would like to modify a value on one of the fields so that it:

1. persists to the database, and
2. becomes available outside the trigger action code where the modification takes place.

Obviously **1)** works.

However, **2)** does not appear to work as expected. The collection in the application code does not hold the modified value that's seen in the trigger action code.

It seems that `Trigger.new[0].MyField__c = 'my value'` is merely a construct to instruct the database but does nothing to modify the collection seen by the calling code that performs `Database.insert(collection)`.

Is *re-querying* (see [forum reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yhuIAA)) the only way to obtain these values in the calling code?

Comment: So, you're assigning a value using `Trigger.new[0].MyField__c = 'my value'` and then a subsequent call to that field returns not `my value` but the value of the field when it entered the trigger? Can you post code that shows what exactly you're doing? Can you assign the value to a String variable, and then use that variable both for the field assignment and subsequent reference?

Answer (score 1):

If you require the value to be available in Apex Classes during the same transaction, you will have to pass the trigger context into the class after you make the changes. Until the transaction is over the result will not be available via SQL anywhere.